# change empty cell to date time object in excel using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, datetime, openpyxl

I am trying to use openpyxl to extract information from an excel workbook and use it to edit word documents. The excel sheet contains information about purchases people have made (such as names, dates and amount of money), so that I can create bills and reminders. It has several columns dedicated to various dates. One for when the first bill was sent per email and subsequent ones for each reminder etc.

The code I have so far works fine with creating bills and reminders already but I want to change is so that I can not only extract the relevant information from the excel sheet but also edit the workbook so that it automatically enters today's date in the right cell when it has created a new bill or reminder for someone.

```
for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=4, max_row=29,min_col=None, max_col=None, values_only=True):
   if row[16] < datetime.datetime.now():
            new_date = ()
            if row[14]!=None:
                row[15] = datetime.datetime.now()
                worbook.save()
                te_factureren_datum = row[15].strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

This is what I have written to iterate though the rows in the sheet. row[16] contains the date a new reminder needs to be sent out as calculated by excel. row[14] is the column containing the date of the previous reminder. What I am trying to achieve I is that, if row[14] is not empty (meaning that a reminder has already been sent out and not paid and the date for a new reminder as indicated by row[16] has already passed), a new reminder is created and today's date is entered into row[15] and saved. When I try to run this it comes back with this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/yvesnohr/Documents/Python/KoKo/PKF script.py", line 51, in <module>
    row[15] = datetime.datetime.now()
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

It seems like it reads the None in the cell as tuple that can not be modified? Could someone explain what is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: If you use `values_only=True` you won't get any cells to work with.

Answer (score 0):

row[15] will basically give you the 14th element in the row array. I think you are looking to update the excel cell, which you cannot do by trying to update row. You will need to use `sheet.cell(row,column).value = New-val`. Also, I am a little unsure of which column you are trying to update. In the code below, this will update column-O (15th row). You may need to adjust it. See if this is what you are looking for..

```
import openpyxl
import datetime
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Sample.xlsx') ##My data file
sheet = wb['Sheet1']
for idx, row in enumerate(sheet.iter_rows(min_row=4, max_row=29,min_col=None, max_col=None, values_only=True)):
    if row[16] < datetime.datetime.now():
            new_date = ()
            if row[14]!=None:
                sheet.cell(row=idx+4, column=15).value = datetime.datetime.now() ##Update that row (4 onwards) and 15th col
#                worbook.save() ##Don't save each time, use save after FOR loop
                te_factureren_datum = sheet.cell(row=idx+4, column=15).value.strftime('%d/%m/%Y') ##Not sure of the purpose, but left it as is

wb.save('Sample.xlsx')
```